# jQuery UI Slider custom step increments and comma on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I'm building a form which uses the "snap to increments" JQuery UI slider: 
https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

This is the code I currently have:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:100,
    min: 2501,
    max: 50000,
    step: 500,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#LoanAmount" ).val( '$' + addCommas(ui.value) );
    }
  });
  $( "#LoanAmount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );

  function addCommas(nStr)
  {
      nStr += '';
      x = nStr.split('.');
      x1 = x[0];
      x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1)) {
          x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      }
      return x1 + x2;
  }
});
</script>
```

My first problem is that the code displays the comma for the value only after the slider gets used but not when the page loads. The page loads with the min value of $2501 instead of $2,501

My second problem is that, for compliance reasons, I need the min amount to be $2,501 instead of $2,500 but I still want the step increments to display on the even 500. I need it to be like this: $2,501 > $3,000 > $3,500 > $4,000 > $4,500, until it finishes on $50,000.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you just manipulate the value in the slide event, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 2501,
      max: 50001,
      step: 500,
      slide: function (event, ui) {
        var x = Number(ui.value);
        if (x > 2501) {
            x = x - (x % 500);
        }
        $("#LoanAmount").val('$' + addCommas(x));
      }
    });
        $("#LoanAmount").val( '$' + addCommas($("#slider").slider("value") ) );

  function addCommas(nStr)
  {
      nStr += '';
      x = nStr.split('.');
      x1 = x[0];
      x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
      var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
      while (rgx.test(x1)) {
          x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
      }
      return x1 + x2;
  }
});
```

See this jsfiddle for an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/bpursley/u1nLma3x/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code works good but the slider ends at $49,500 instead of $50,00. Any solution for that? Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, just change your slider max to 50001 and it will go to 50000.  I updated my answer and the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bpursley/u1nLma3x/7/

Comment: Hey bpursley, sorry to bug again. I decided to use a default slider value of 5000 but when page load it prints as 5001. Any tips on how to fix that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have to see your code, can you edit your question or post a new question with the code for his problem?

Comment: Hey @bpursley thanks for all you help. Here is the new question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813696/jquery-ui-slider-default-value-issues-when-using-custom-step-increments

Answer (score 2):

First heres an easy way to add commas to text, not 100% sure if its supported on all browesers though so use with caution

```
textvalue = Number(nStr).toLocaleString('en',{minimumFractionDigits: 0 });
```

For your first problem do this

```
$( "#LoanAmount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

should be

```
$( "#LoanAmount" ).val( "$" + addCommas($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )) );
```

As for the second issue an easy hack would be set the starting value to 2501, then in your slide function do this

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
  var val = ui.value
  if(val === 2500){
     val = 2501
  }
  else{
     val = val / 10
     val = Math.round(val)
     val = val * 10 
  }

  $( "#LoanAmount" ).val( '$' + addCommas(val) );
}
```

I think this will work, basically you check to see if value is 2500 then you set it to 2501, but then you have to make sure that when you step you round back to an even 500 number

**EDIT**

fixed bug with code

Comment: Hey Charles, thanks for your help. My First problem got fixed but when trying your second code the slider stop working altogether. It won't slide anymore.

Comment: oh look at the line 
 var val = us.value
it should be 
 var val = ui.value

you should be able to open the debugger tools and get error mssages

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Thanks Charles. Although the first awnser did the trick for me, I wanted to test your code to let you know how it worked. The slider works now, but the it prints $2,500 on page load, it changes to $2,501 only when the slider gets used and slid back to the minimum.

Comment: could i'm glad you figured it out, would you mind upvoting mine for helping you? and to fix that you would just set min val to 2501

Comment: I did but I still don't have 15 points in reputation so the vote will appear eventually. FYI I did try changing the min value to 2501 but it did the opposite. Page loaded with the correct 2501 but after sliding to the min it changed to 2500

Comment: lol ok well the guy up there had a more elegant solution anyways, thanks for trying :)