# jQuery UI Slider default value issues when using custom step increments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm building a form using the "snap to increments" JQuery UI Slider: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

I'm using the following code so that the slider has a custom min of 2501 but still increments on the even 500 (without adding that extra 1) until it reaches a max of 50000. So the step increments look like this: 2501 > 3000 > 3500 > 4000 etc. until it reaches 50000.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 10000,
    min: 2501,
    max: 50001,
    step: 500,
    range: "min",
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var x = Number(ui.value);
      if (x > 2501) {
        x = x - (x % 500);
      }
      $("#LoanAmount").val('$' + addCommas(x));
    }
  });
  $("#LoanAmount").val('$' + addCommas($("#slider").slider("value")));

  function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
  }
});
</script>
```

I need to have that ***value: 10000*** so that the slider loads on that specific step, but the problem is that it prints on the page as 10001 instead of 10000.

Any tips on how to tackle this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to correct your addCommas function:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 10000,
    min: 2501,
    max: 50500,
    step: 500,
    range: "min",
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      var x = Number(ui.value);
      if (x > 2501) {
        x = x - (x % 500);
      }
      $("#amount").val('$' + addCommas(x));
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val('$' + addCommas($("#slider").slider("value")));

  function addCommas(nStr) {
    var x = Number(nStr);
    if (x > 2501) {
        x = x - (x % 500);
    }
    nStr = x.toString();
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>
    <label for="amount">Amount ($50 increments):</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Hey @gaemaf thanks for your help. The problem is that for compliance reasons, is a must to have the min value set to 2501. Your code changed that value back to 2500.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Works like a charm. As soon as my reputation reaches 15 your vote will appear. Thanks again for the help.